# Creating sequence of lists from content of one list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Trying to solve the following problem:

I have a large collection which I will represent by the following example list:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

How do I splice up this list and return a sequence of delimited strings for every four elements in the list?

Desired output:

```
1, 2, 3, 4
5, 6, 7, 8
9, 10, 11, 12
13, 14, 15, 16
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]

new_list = [l[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(l), 4)]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

Comment: Answering low effort questions is encouraging low effort questions.

Comment: Thanks for adding the link above and helping me find one of several other possible solutions.  This comment here at the bottom, however, is altogether unnecessary and discouraging.

Comment: @JamieStrausbaugh Glad to help!